# Screen rotate 90 degrees for a second after taking a picture

Tags: android

My problem is this, after I take a picture using-

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 2);
    }
}
```

And after I am saving the picture to file system and presenting the picture on ImageView-

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
       try{
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        File picFile=createImageFile();
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(picFile);
        imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fo);
        fo.close();

        //rotating the picture if its rotated wrong
        ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(FileAbsPath);
        int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

        switch(orientation) {
               case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                   Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                   matrix.postRotate(90);
                   imageBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(imageBitmap, 0, 0, imageBitmap.getWidth(), imageBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                   break;
               case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                   Matrix matrix2 = new Matrix();
                   matrix2.postRotate(180);
                   imageBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(imageBitmap, 0, 0, imageBitmap.getWidth(), imageBitmap.getHeight(), matrix2, true);
                   break;
               // etc.
        }

        myBitMap=imageBitmap;
        if (mImageView.getMeasuredHeight()>0){
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(myBitMap);
        }
       }catch (IOException e) {System.out.println("exception catched.");}
    }
}
```

What sometimes happens is that when I'm using the app, right after I am taking the picture, and choosing "save", and coming back to my app, the entire screen (including the picture) is rotated by 90 degrees clockwise for just a second, then it comes back to regular portrait mode.

It doesn't happen always, but happens most of the time.

This problem is not related to the `switch` `case` of whether or not the picture is rotated (it happend even if this section is not there) and it happend even if I define my activity to be a portrait activity.

I figured out this is not a problem with my phone bcause in apps like whatsap this problem does not happen, so there most be a code to handle this.

Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: It happens because the camera app is locked to either landscape or portrait. In your manifest add this to your activity `android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"` and see the result

Comment: Can you direct me to a documentation about this camera lock and it's connection to `android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"`? I couldn't find any

Comment: errr, from what I know (not documented) the camera is locked into one orientation. Therefore is your app is locked to the opposite, you will get the strange jarring when switching between the two. This is common for any apps.

Comment: It doesn't work. I added what you said but it still happens. (sometimes)